# Microservice Circuit Breaker and Discovery Service patterns

Tags: microservices, circuit-breaker

I'm new to microservices and have this doubt that google hasn't really helped me out.
I know that a microservice has to be independent, so even if one of its counterpart goes offline, one should keep working normally.

Having that in mind, I can't really understand circuit breaker or even service discovery, like where should do I put it? Since every call I make to any microservice goes through the circuit breaker, let's say my Circuit Breaker  service's server goes offline, so my whole application is doomed until I fix it. How to go around that?

Most importantly, WHERE should I put the Circuit Breaker, in a microservice as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should use the Circuit breaker pattern whenever you have remote calls**.

If you don't use it, then in some circumstances (i.e. when some microservices are down) your system would act as it is under a self DOS attack. This situation manifests itself when you have chained synchronous calls. For example, if you have the following: A -> B -> C (A calls B which calls C). If C is not responding and A keeps calling then B could be overwhelmed with managing waiting calls from A and could not respond to legitimate calls from other services that would normally succeed.

The most common place to use the Circuit breaker is in the API Gateway, where most of the remote calls are made (this is it's primary responsibility). You could use the pattern also in clients, to force them stop continuously and repeatedly calling a dead microservice.

Although microservices are independent with regards to resilience (they could function even when other fail), this does not mean that they don't communicate with one another. They may communicate but in an asynchronous manner, i.e. when one microservices wants to update its own local cache with data from another microservice in a background process.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Just like I thought, the circuit breaker needs to be implemented on the API. But bear with me, what if the circuit breaker's service goes offline? That's what I'm confused with. Like, all the calls to my APIs are narrowed to this shallow canal, so if something happens and it closes, then my application will not work.
Is that really it, or am I missing something?

Comment: @VandersonAssis yes, if the circuit goes *open* then the app will not work anymore **but it wasn't working anyway**. The upstream service wasn't working anyway. But because the circuit is now open (it doesn't forward requests but fail fast) the defect upstream service has a greater possibility of recovery. Also, the API can still forward requests for the other upstream services that are healthy. Without a circuit breaker the API will die too because of too many waiting calls to the defect upstream service.

Comment: [1 ]No, I don't mean it going open, I mean it going offline. The circuit breaker is nothing more than a service too, right? My question is, what if the circuit breaker itself goes offline, then all the calls to it will fail, therefore my app will no longer work until I fix it.

As far as I know, microservices are independent and should operate normally even if one or more other microservices goes offline. That's really good, I like this idea. But reading a lot about circuit breakers I still have doubts, like all the calls to my microservices goes through the circuit breaker.

Comment: [2]
So if a circuit breaker fails, then all my application fails as well, because it will not longer be able to forward the requests since it's offline. That kind of doesn't break the whole idea of having independent services?

Comment: [1] and [2]: a circuit breaker should run in-process, and not as a separate microservice so it cannot really fail

Comment: Thanks for the help! It makes much more sense now. =]